# How can I implement MRProgress in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3

The docs are unclear as to how to implement this beautiful library in Swift

I can import MRProgress and get the blurred overlayView to appear but I can't get the progress to update

// Attempt one: can't get view to show or params to change 
```

```
var overlay = MRProgressOverlayView()

upload.uploadProgress(closure: { //Get Progress
   progress in

   print(progress.fractionCompleted) // double 

   progressFloat = Float(progress.fractionCompleted) // float

   if progress.fractionCompleted < 1 {

       // Here are some options but they are not working 

       self.overlay.mode = .determinateCircular

       self.overlay.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 80)

       self.overlay.setTintColor(UIColor.blue)

       self.overlay.titleLabelText = "Uploading!"

       self.overlay.show(true)

       self.overlay.progress = progressFloat

       self.overlay.setProgress(progressFloat, animated: true)
  }

  if progress.fractionCompleted == 1 {
        print("Completed")

        // remove progress 
        self.overlay.dismiss(true)

  }
```

```

// Attempt two: View appears but setProgress throws error

```
 MRProgressOverlayView.showOverlayAdded(to: self.view, title: "Uploading", mode: .determinateCircular, animated: true)

 MRProgress.setProgress(floatProgress, true)
 // error
 // Use of instance member 'setProgress' on type 'MRProgressOverlayView'; did you mean to use a value of type 'MRProgressOverlayView' instead?
```

from the src

```
/**
 Change progress animated.

 The animation will be always linear.

 @param progress The new progress value.
 @param animated Specify YES to animate the change or NO if you do not want the change to be animated.
 */
open func setProgress(_ progress: Float, animated: Bool)
```

Can anyone tell me how I can use this beautiful looking library please ??
Finally, could someone with 1500+ rep please add the tag for MRProgress

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
let overlay = MRProgressOverlayView.showOverlayAdded(to: self.view, title: "Uploading", mode: .determinateCircular, animated: true)

upload.uploadProgress(closure: { //Get Progress
      progress in

      print(progress.fractionCompleted)

      self.progressFloat = Float(progress.fractionCompleted)

      if progress.fractionCompleted < 1 {

                 overlay?.setProgress(self.progressFloat, animated: true)

      }

      if progress.fractionCompleted == 1 {
               print("Completed")

                overlay?.dismiss(true)                                
       }
```

})